# Primer proyecto de inventario y no encuentro el error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bueno como ven en el titulo, es mi primer proyecto y la verdad, no encuentro la falla en el programa, asi que me dispuse a preguntar aca. Dejo el codigo mas abajo, sospecho que es en la def buscar, pero no se que puede fallar.
Recien empiezo, por lo que cualquier consejo o error que ven y comenten es mas que bienvenido.

```
from typing import final

producto = str(input("Ingresa un elemento a la lista: "))
cantidad = int(input("Ingresa cuanto compraste de ese producto: "))

fabrica = [producto, cantidad]
# puede ser que no funcione porque me guarda las funciones y no las variables
compras = []
# definidas las dos listas, una es de lo que hay y otra es para lo que hay que comprar

def buscar(fabrica):
   p_buscar = str(input("Busca un elemento: "))
   if p_buscar in fabrica:
      print(p_buscar, "ya esta comprado.")
    # no me toma lo que esta en la lista
    # que falla de esto?
   if p_buscar not in fabrica:
      print("Ese elemento no esta en la lista, hay que comprarlo.")
    # me baja directamente aca
    agregar(fabrica)
    print(fabrica)
    # estas dos ultimas lineas no las lee
# funcion para buscar en la lista fabrica

def agregar(fabrica):
   p_agregar = str(input("Ingrese un elemento para agregar a la lista fabrica"))
   if p_agregar not in fabrica:
    fabrica.append(p_agregar)
   if p_agregar in fabrica:
    print("El elemento ya fue agregado!")
 # funcion para buscar un elemento en la lista y agregarlo


usuario = str(input("Queres hacer algo mas? (agregar, salir o buscar): "))
while usuario != "salir":
    if usuario == "agregar":
        agregar(fabrica)
    if usuario == "buscar":
        buscar(fabrica)        
    if usuario == "salir":
        print("Muchas gracias por agregar los productos.")
```

edit: recien vi los comentarios y tienen razon, me colgue en decir cual es el problea, mil disculpas.
Cuando ejecuto el codigo e ingreso datos en los inputs 'producto' y 'cantidad', quiero ejecutar la funcion buscar (poniendo 'buscar' en la variable 'usuario') y es ahi donde, cuando pongo un elemento que ya busque (supongamos que busco el producto 'aceite') me salta que el producto no esta en la lista 'fabrica', cuando en el input 'producto' si lo ingrese. Desde ya otra vez disculpas y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Y... se tiene que adivinar el error o nos darás una pista?

Comment: No nos dice que hace tu código ni donde falla (¿se cae? ¿no da el resultado?) Tampoco das datos de entrada y el resultado esperado. No sólo nos pides resolver tu problema; ni siquiera nos dices cual es el problema.

Comment: Bienvenido Matias Rico a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: gracias patricio, sin dudas ya lo leo para no mandarme mas como esta!

Answer (score 2):

En Python es muy importante la [indentación](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Al no tener llaves `{}` ni estructuras `begin` - `end`, la delimitación de los bloques se hace de esta forma. En tu código tienes indentación incoherente, hay partes que tienen 3 espacios, otras 2 o 4 y otras están a nivel distinto en el mismo bloque.

Por otro lado, no se si es obligatorio usar listas, pero qué tal si en vez, usas una estructura de datos tipo diccionario, con un código único de producto como llave (key) y una lista con la descripción del mismo (value). Datos de ejemplo:

```
inventario = {
    "123" : ["Aceite de motor 10W30", 27],
    "124" : ["Aceite 15W40", 22],
    "132" : ["Filtro de Aire", 15]
}
```

Propongo este modelo porque es más parecido a como trabaja un sistema en el mundo real con bases de datos. Puedes tener 30 tipos de "aceite", pero id del producto es quien identifica a cada uno y es un dato más fácilmente utilizable, por ejemplo, en un escáner de códigos de barra o una PDA. 
Modificando un poco tu programa para que trabaje con ese tipo de estructura:

```
import os, json # <-- nuevo

inventario = {}

def write_json(filename): # <-- nuevo (toda la funcion)
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(inventario, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)

def agregar():
    cod = input("Ingresa un codigo para el producto: ")
    if cod not in inventario:
        pr_nom = input("Ingresa el nombre del producto: ")
        pr_can = int(input("Cantidad del producto: "))
        inventario[cod] = [pr_nom, pr_can]
        write_json(db_file) # <-- nuevo
        print("Producto agregado!!")
    else:
        print("[!] Lo sentimos, ya hay un producto con este código")
    
def buscar():
    encontrados = [] # Encontrado
    cod = input("Buscar por CODIGO (deje vacio para buscar por nombre): ")
    if cod:
        if cod in inventario:
            encontrados.append([cod, inventario[cod]])
    else:
        buscar = input("Buscar por NOMBRE de producto: ")
        for cod, prod in inventario.items():
            nom_prod = prod[0]
            if nom_prod.lower().find(buscar.lower()) >= 0:
                encontrados.append([cod, inventario[cod]])
    if encontrados:
        print("- Producto encontrado -")
        for elem in encontrados:
            print(f"COD# {elem[0]} --- {elem[1][0]} --- CANT: {elem[1][1]}")
    else:
        print("[!] El producto no se encuentra")

db_file = 'inventario.json' # <-- nuevo
if not os.path.exists(db_file): # <-- nuevo
    write_json(db_file) # Si no existe, crearlo # <-- nuevo
with open(db_file, 'r') as f: # Lee el archivo actual # <-- nuevo
    inventario = json.load(f) # <-- nuevo

usuario = None
while usuario != "s":
    usuario = input("¿Qué deseas hacer? ([a]gregar, [b]uscar o [s]alir): ")
    if usuario == "a":
        agregar()
    elif usuario == "b":
        buscar()
    elif usuario == "s":
        print("Muchas gracias por agregar los productos.")
```

[Edición] Contestando preguntas de los comentarios:
La linea de código que mencionas es una interpolación literal (Python 3.6 o superior). Reemplaza la variable que esté dentro de `{}` por su valor respectivo. Es una forma simple e intuitiva de imprimir valores sin romper la cadena. Ver [documentación respectiva](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)
Es lo mismo que:

```
print("COD# " + elem[0] + " --- " + elem[1][0] + " --- CANT: " + str(elem[1][1]))
```

o

```
print("COD# {} --- {} --- CANT: {}".format(elem[0], elem[1][0], elem[1][1]))
```

¿Por qué no se pasan valores a las funciones? Esto es porque `inventario` es una [Variable Global](https://www.google.com/search?q=programacion+variable+global), vale dentro de todos los ámbitos, ya que está declarada al principio del programa.
ADVERTENCIA [!!!] Esto es basado en opiniones, pero en consenso NO es buena práctica usar variables globales y casi no hay motivo que justifique su uso. En este caso, `inventario`, es una "pseudo base de datos" y como tal puede (y debe) tener un alcance global en el código. De todas formas se puede pasar `inventario` como parámetro de función y también debería funcionar. Te aconsejo [leas esto](https://docs.python.org/es/dev/faq/programming.html#id8).

Es más, por qué no guardas los datos localmente en un archivo en disco y así cada vez que ejecutas el script, no los tienes que volver a agregar. Para ello cree una función llamada `write_json()` y se agregaron un par de líneas, te las he señalizado con `# <-- nuevo`

Comment: Mil gracias por la ayuda, ya corrijo la identacion, tengo varios problemas con eso jaja

Comment: te hago una cosulta igualmente sobre esta linea de codigo que no me quedo claro como funciona, gracias
print(f"COD# {elem[0]} --- {elem[1][0]} --- CANT: {elem[1][1]}")

Comment: y para saber, cuando definis las funciones no definis ningun valor dentro de los parentesis, esto por que es? Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: @MatiasRico te he respondido en el post tus preguntas, adicional hice una modificación para guardar en un archivo de disco los datos. Si no lo deseas así, puedes omitir esas líneas.

Comment: tu código se puede simplificar bastante si usas comprensiones de listas y simplificas una que otra operación y usas algunos *truquitos*

Comment: Gracias @aeportugal.

Comment: @Christian que truquitos? Soy iniciado en python, asi que estoy mas que seguro que se puede simplificar mas. Como lo harias? Gracias!

Comment: Utilizaria un operador ternario para cambiar el modo de apertura del archivo, así simplificas el código redundante. Esos `if` largos se pueden reducir con un diccionario. También se puede modificar un poco el `input` de la función `buscar` con el fin de reducir un poco el código

Answer (score 1):

```
from typing import final

producto = str(input("Ingresa un elemento a la lista: "))
cantidad = int(input("Ingresa cuanto compraste de ese producto: "))

fabrica = [producto, cantidad]
# puede ser que no funcione porque me guarda las funciones y no las 
variables
compras = []
# definidas las dos listas, una es de lo que hay y otra es para lo que 
hay que comprar

def buscar(fabrica):
   p_buscar = str(input("Busca un elemento: "))
   if p_buscar in fabrica:
     print(p_buscar, "ya esta comprado.")
   elif p_buscar not in fabrica:
      print("Ese elemento no esta en la lista, hay que comprarlo.")
      agregar(fabrica)
# funcion para buscar en la lista fabrica

def agregar(fabrica):
   p_agregar = str(input("Ingrese un elemento para agregar a la lista 
fabrica"))
   if p_agregar not in fabrica:
     fabrica.append(p_agregar)
     print(fabrica)
   elif p_agregar in fabrica:
     print("El elemento ya fue agregado!")
     # funcion para buscar un elemento en la lista y agregarlo


usuario = str(input("Queres hacer algo mas? (agregar, salir o buscar): 
"))
while usuario != "salir":
  if usuario == "agregar":
    agregar(fabrica)
  elif usuario == "buscar":
    buscar(fabrica)        
  elif usuario == "salir":
    print("Muchas gracias por agregar los productos.")
```

Comment: creo que solo tenias fallos de indentacion en linea 20,21 y 22

Comment: Añade una explicación a tu respuesta

Comment: creo que solo tenias fallos de indentacion en linea 20,21 y 22, el resto me ha funcionado bien, si te da fallos envia el fallo que te da o dime cual es.

Comment: Christian se refiere a que edites la respuesta y agregues la explicación allí.

Comment: @JavierFiestasBotella, sabes que no estoy seguro, mas que nada porque lo que busco es que se ejecute la funcion si ese if se ejecuta.

Comment: Código sin indicar cómo usarlo o por qué resuelve la pregunta, es una respuesta de baja calidad.